# How to restore iOS app to foreground by tapping status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS native Phone app, when you answer a call, you can send the Phone app to background and do anything else, but the status bar will enable to restore the Phone app at anytime by tapping on it like the below image.

The questions is: How can I apply that behavior programmatically in my iOS app?

[image]

Comment: Simply put, you can't. It part of the OS (as in iOS). Give me an example and I'll gladly delete this comment - but PLEASE, not an example of an Apple app like you have. A third party one.

Comment: Skype has this feature, and i think many VoIP apps as well.

Comment: That's because they are using an API to perform voice calls, which automatically does that. If your app is a VoIP app then it can do that by using that background mode, otherwise you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't. That's a feature reserved for the Phone and Maps apps.

Comment: I think third-party VoIP apps has this feature.

Comment: Yeah, but I think that's because it's using CallKit, so during a call the app is essentially acting as the stock Phone app, so it gets that status bar feature for free.